# Difference between Keras' DenseNet201, DenseNet169, and DenseNet121

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-processing

I have been trying to use DenseNet architecture for the CIFAR-10 dataset. For the first trial I used [DenseNet201](https://keras.io/api/applications/densenet/), and got around [79% validation accuracy](https://www.kaggle.com/mooncrater/cifar-10-with-densenets-transfer-learning), which is pretty less than what I expected.

So I wondered if it made sense to switch the DenseNet structure. I'm assuming that the 201, 169 and 121 are the depth of the model. So would it make sense to use a somewhat shallow model?

I'm not sure that every assumption I've mentioned here is true.

Any advice is appreciated.